# AngularJS - Special Characters in JSON and Coldfusion Request

Tags: angularjs, json, string, serialization, coldfusion

I'm trying to use a JSON string for doing an INSERT in a database . I'm using AngularJS and Coldfusion for doing that.

Thanks to a form I retrieve data, I create an object in the service (controller) and thanks to a factory I do an $http.post. My problem concerns the string sent to it: the string contains special chars (for instance "&" and I don't know how to treat this kind of issue.

Here an example of the string sent:

```
jsStruct={"LASTNAME":"Nämé","FIRSTN%a£öME":"TestFirstName","PHONENUMBER":48484488,"EMAIL":"tes.test@test.test","COMPANY":"Test & Comp"}
```

***My controller:***

```
app.controller('ctrlAddContacts', function ($scope, ContactService){

    // WHEN SUBMITTING THE FORM -> SEND THE DATA STRING 
    $scope.submitForm = function(contact){
        if($scope.ContactForm.$valid){

            // CALL THE FACTORY -> SEND THE DATA STRING 
            ContactService.addNewPerson(contact).success(function(Person){
                $scope.ContactForm.$setPristine();
                $scope.contact= Person;     

            });     
        }
    }
});
```

***My Factory:***

```
app.factory('ContactService', function($http){

    var factory={};

    factory.addNewPerson=function(objContact){

        return $http.post('http://myapp/contacts.cfc?method=addNewPerson&jsStruct=' + JSON.stringify(objContact))
    };  

    return factory;

})
```

***In my Coldfusion component "contacts.cfc":***

```
    <cffunction name="addNewPerson" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="no">    
        <cfargument name="jsStruct" type="string" required="true">
        <cfset var cfStruct=DeserializeJSON(jsStruct)>

        ..................

    </cffunction>
```

I obtain this error on the server because in my string there is *"COMPANY":"Test & Comp"*:

```
JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem and prevent special characters used by Coldfusion and Oracle as &, #, ', " and others?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the issue you facing with special char.?

Comment: I added some information about my problem. On the server during the treatment I obtain the error: `'JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string` because I have special char in the string (for instance `&`)

Comment: I just tested your JSON. I parsed it, but no error.

Comment: Not related to your question, but why is your function for inserting data returning json?

Comment: For using to my Coldfusion component

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In fact we asked to the DBA to change the DSN to use different driver and the problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

I just tried parsing your JSON. It worked for me. I guess the **JSON parser** used on server end do not support special char.

```js
var jsStruct={"LASTNAME":"Nämé","FIRSTN%a£öME":"TestFirstName","PHONENUMBER":48484488,"EMAIL":"tes.test@test.test","COMPANY":"Test & Comp"};

var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsStruct));
console.log(parsedJSON,"parsedJSON")
```

Edit 1:

As per your error message: JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string

You're trying to parse a string as JSON, and the string isn't JSON. Error is not for special character.